# XGBoost predictions not working on AI Platform: 'features names mismatch'

Tags: pandas, machine-learning, google-cloud-platform, xgboost, google-cloud-ml

I have deployed an XGBoost model on GCP's AI Platform (ex-ML Engine) to make predictions (it is stored on GCS as a joblib file). But, when I try to make predictions on a list of features, I get a 'features mismatch' error.

AI Platform requires a specific format for input data :

[image: An instances list]

Also, when I test predictions on JupyterLab, the `.predict` method of my classifier works when I give it a DataFrame, but does not if I try to make predictions on arrays or single rows of the DataFrame.

The error message I obtain (both on AI Platform and JupyterLab) is

```
{
  "error": "Prediction failed: Exception during sklearn prediction:
 feature_names mismatch: [THE FEATURES LIST] ['f0', 'f1', 'f2', 'f3', 'f4', 'f5', 'f6', 'f7', 'f8', 'f9', 'f10', 'f11', 'f12', 'f13', 'f14', 'f15', 'f16', 'f17', 'f18', 'f19', 'f20', 'f21', 'f22', 'f23', 'f24', 'f25', 'f26', 'f27', 'f28', 'f29', 'f30', 'f31', 'f32', 'f33', 'f34', 'f35', 'f36', 'f37', 'f38', 'f39', 'f40', 'f41', 'f42', 'f43', 'f44', 'f45', 'f46', 'f47', 'f48', 'f49', 'f50', 'f51', 'f52', 'f53', 'f54', 'f55', 'f56']
\nexpected [THE FEATURES LIST BUT NOT IN THE SAME ORDER] in input data
\ntraining data did not have the following fields: f23, f14, f41, f6, f19, f35, f5, f49, f50, f18, f25, f45, f36, f21, f42, f0, f2, f37, f44, f47, f16, f22, f1, f3, f8, f53, f33, f11, f38, f48, f12, f31, f39, f27, f40, f52, f26, f29, f43, f20, f4, f10, f7, f13, f28, f9, f56, f24, f17, f32, f34, f54, f51, f15, f30, f46, f55"
}
```

Maybe the input I give is not what is expected. But it seems there is not other input option on AI Platform. What I look for is a solution specifically for Google Cloud's AI Platform.

Comment: Do you want to take a look at this notebook: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloudml-samples/blob/master/notebooks/xgboost/Training%20and%20Prediction%20with%20XGBoost.ipynb this may help.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem by setting the version's framework to `XGBoost` (it was previously `sklearn`) and I uploaded a `.bst` file in the bucket instead of a `.joblib`

Thanks for your help @user260826 :)

Answer (score 1):

TLDR: Just before saving to the bucket do this: `model.feature_names = None`

I ran into this issue too. Like you, I solved it by uploading a `.bst` file into the bucket. I wanted to investigate a little more and here are my findings.

Suppose the model is saved via joblib `joblib.dump(xgbm, 'model.joblib')`.

Then, loading the model, `model = joblib.load("model.joblib")` and calling `model.feature_names`, will give you the list of feature names, implying the list of features is stored somewhere within the `model.joblib` file.

However, the request to AI Platform does not include the list of column names(AFAIK there is no way to include it unless you are doing a custom prediction routine) so it throws the feature_names mismatch error when google tries to do something along the lines of `model.predict(xgb.DMatrix(np.asarray(instances)))`.

The same is true if the model is saved using pickle.

If the model is saved as a `.bst`, then calling `model.feature_names` will be empty and everything works since neither the model nor the prediction instances has information on the list of features.